# Is the ClaimedIdentifier the unique one (DotNetOpenAuth)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm using now DotNetOpenAuth for doing login with OpenId

I looked at their OpenIdRelyingPartyMvcDemo and at the NerdDinner mvc demo

and both applications are using the `response.ClaimedIdentifier` to log in the users, e.g.

```
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(response.ClaimedIdentifier, false);
```

so I just want to be sure, **is this the one that is unique for each user, and it will never change?** (so that I could save it in my DB and bind it to everything needed)

*I see many SO posts says it's VerifiedIdetifier but the DotNetOpenAuth response object doesnt has this*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.  `ClaimedIdentifier` is the unique string you should bind everything to.  There's no such thing as a VerifiedIdentifier.  If you can link to any of those SO questions/answers I'll correct them.